# Adding expressions to ggplot axis tick marks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add something like 10^ to each tick mark label on my X and/or Y axis tick labels.

I know this can be done in `facet_grid` by using a labeller like `label_bquote` but I am curious if there is a way to do this for tick labels.

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(rows = vars(drv),labeller = label_bquote(rows=sigma==10^.(drv)))
```

This example code adds 10^ to the labels of each facet row and, as of now, if I want to add 10^ to each X axis tick then I would do something along the lines of:

```
p + 
 scale_x_continuous(labels = expression("10"^"2", "10"^"3", "10"^"4", "10"^"5", "10"^"6", "10"^"7"), 
                    breaks = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```

**My Question Is:**

Is there a built-in function that will allow me to add an expression to each break? My current method leaves room for human error.

Comment: See the example in `?annotation_logticks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the tip about `annotation_logticks` I was able to find the following code:
`scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::math_format(10^.x))` which does exactly what I was looking for.